# Handle notifications with Combine in Swift with removeDuplicated() sometimes does not cache notifications

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have problem with catching notifications from default `NotificationCenter`. Sometimes it does not receive it at all.

Code example below:

```
NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notifications.userNotification)
    .removeDuplicates()
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { self.handle(notification: $0) }
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

As soon as I remove `.removeDuplicates()` line it starts to receive all notifications.
The question is: do I really need this line? Is it really helpful/important?
I was searching for good example with `.removeDuplicates()` usage for `NotificationCenter`, but could not find anything.
Could someone explain me, why it is like that?

**Update**:

In my case the `Notification`s used for navigation inside the app. It has `userInfo` dictionary with information like: `["navigateTo" : "viewControllerTypeShoppingCart"]` or `["navigateTo" : "viewControllerTypeWishList"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeDuplicates` removes (not surprisingly), duplicate events from the Publisher output -- specifically, events that pass the `Equatable` check (`==`).

With `Notification`s, for example, this could be `Notification`s with the same `Notification.Name`. However, if the `userInfo` dictionaries are different, the equality test will fail. For example:

```
let n = Notification(name: Notification.Name("test"), object: nil, userInfo: ["test":"hi"])
let n2 = Notification(name: Notification.Name("test2"), object: nil, userInfo: ["test":"hi"])
let n3 = Notification(name: Notification.Name("test"), object: nil, userInfo: ["test2":"hi"])
let n4 = Notification(name: Notification.Name("test"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
let n5 = Notification(name: Notification.Name("test"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
print("Equal?", n == n2, n == n3, n4 == n5)
```

Results in:

```
Equal? false false true
```

You don't list any information about what type of `Notification` you're receiving, but if it were, for example, an event that happened where there isn't a `userInfo` dictionary with differing information, you'll miss any repeated events, as they'll look like duplicates.

Is it helpful? It depends on your use case. Important? Same thing?
It seems like in your case, if `removeDuplicates` is causing undesirable behavior, you should remove it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case the notification used to navigate to different ViewControllers. The userInfo dictionary contains different values, but sometimes it has the same vales, because for example the user navigates to the same view controller twice or more.

Comment: Ok. I’m not sure that this changes anything about my answer.